# POLL - Especially new users: Did you notice our disclaimers?

Tags: discussion, pre-migration

We have a few disclaimers around the site, designed to keep people from using mi.yodeya as a source of professional rabbinic advice (pesak). There's one, in red, at the top of every page, one in the "How to Ask" box on the "Ask a Question" page, and one in the FAQ.

I am [thinking](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/409/make-for-yourself-a-website/414#414) about beefing these up in format and/or content, but first, I want to know how well they're performing now.

So, if everyone could answer at least one of the following questions, it would be quite valuable to me:

1. Did you notice any of these disclaimers the first time you came to mi.yodeya?

   If not, how long did it take? (Did you first notice when you read this question?)
2. Do you find anything in these disclaimers unclear, ambiguous, or incomplete?

Thanks very much.

Comment: The red banner that goes all across the top is how I know I'm not logged in.

Answer (score 5):

1. Yes.
2. It is unclear because there are many people out there who are unaware of the dictum "Make for yourself a Rav." There should be a third line saying "The correct approach to getting an answer for a Halachic question is to ask a qualified Rabbi." This way there is an actual instruction as to the correct approach in receiving guidance for halachic queries.

Answer (score 3):

1. Saw it right away.
2. Look forward to the content growing to a point where the rabbis will be contributing and using it as well. Would help to have the system tied into an online, translated repository of all our sources.

Keep it up. Awesome site.

Comment: thelevite, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for your ideas. Believe it or not, we already have community members who are rabbis. However, any advice they offer here is still in their capacity as part of the "crowd of your friends," not as professional rabbinic advice.

Answer (score 3):

I first noticed it when I read this question

Answer (score 2):

1. It's at the top. And in red.

Comment: I'd be interested to see you articulate what you're getting at more fully, either as a question on mi.yodeya, if it makes sense as one; or as an email to info@yodeya.com. (Or, if you want to try it, you can take it to our discussion forum, ani.yodeya.com, but as you'll see, that's pretty vestigial now, and we're not putting the energy into promoting it.)

Comment: I've edited my comments out of this topic, as they do not belong here.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes. However, gradually it lost its impact.
2. Perfectly clear - to me at least.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes.
2. No, but only because I held by CYLOR before I ever found this site.  Others who don't CYLOR will take it about as seriously as "ask your doctor before" starting a diet, exercise program, OTC medications, etc.